# Can we mock the app behavior using OCMock in iOS ? For Instance, I want to mock App is Terminated Or App entered background for Test cases

Tags: unit-testing

Is it possible to Mock App Behaviors using OCMock for test cases. I would like to write few test cases when app gets terminated or app goes to background.
I want to mock "app is terminated" for test case.
Similarly, I want to mock "app entered background" for test case.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't involve mocking. Make test code that invokes your application delegate, calling:

- `applicationWillTerminate:` or
- `applicationWillEnterBackground:`

Comment: Thanks Jon for your answer.

Comment: @Braj Please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful.